# MariaDB BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-error-1064, freeradius

I've been reading about this error but can't find how to fix this error.
I do have a schedule every hour of this sentence:

```
 UPDATE radacct SET 
            radacct.AcctStopTime=NOW(),
            radacct.AcctTerminateCause='Stale-Session'
        WHERE ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(radacct.acctstarttime) + radacct.acctsessiontime)) > (60*6+60*6))
            AND (AcctStopTime = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR AcctStopTime IS NULL)
```

And some times i'm getting this error:

```
 BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(unix_timestamp(now()) - (unix_timestamp(`radius`.`radacct`.`acctstarttime`) + `radius`.`radacct`.`acctsessiontime`))'
```

This is the create table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `radacct` (
   `radacctid` bigint(21) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `acctsessionid` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `acctuniqueid` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `username` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `groupname` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `realm` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
   `nasipaddress` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `nasportid` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `nasporttype` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `acctstarttime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `acctupdatetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `acctstoptime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `acctinterval` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
   `acctsessiontime` int(12) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `acctauthentic` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `connectinfo_start` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `connectinfo_stop` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `acctinputoctets` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `acctoutputoctets` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `calledstationid` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `callingstationid` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL      DEFAULT '',
   `acctterminatecause` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL      DEFAULT '',
   `servicetype` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `framedprotocol` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `framedipaddress` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   PRIMARY KEY (`radacctid`),
   UNIQUE KEY `acctuniqueid` (`acctuniqueid`),
   KEY `username` (`username`),
   KEY `framedipaddress` (`framedipaddress`),
   KEY `acctsessionid` (`acctsessionid`),
   KEY `acctsessiontime` (`acctsessiontime`),
   KEY `acctstarttime` (`acctstarttime`),
   KEY `acctinterval` (`acctinterval`),
   KEY `acctstoptime` (`acctstoptime`),
   KEY `nasipaddress` (`nasipaddress`),
   KEY `callingstationid` (`callingstationid`) USING BTREE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14270573 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8      COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Added:

SHOW variables LIKE 'sql_mode'

'sql_mode', 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'

Added 2:

This is the final query working perfect as suggest @Rick James

```
 UPDATE radacct SET 
            radacct.AcctStopTime=NOW(),
            radacct.AcctTerminateCause='Stale-Session'
        WHERE (  NOW() - interval (60*6+60*6) second  >  radacct.acctstarttime + interval radacct.acctsessiontime second  )
            AND (AcctStopTime = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR AcctStopTime IS NULL)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please, provide some test data, specifically the relevant columns.

Comment: I can't get them. Don't know how to do it. Just now i've been trying select data and got this error: Error Code: 1690. BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(1467576800 - (unix_timestamp(`radius`.`radacct`.`acctstarttime`) + `radius`.`radacct`.`acctsessiontime`))' 0.016 sec    ...   but then I can't list wich rows cause the error. This table is relly poulated and changing every second .... How can I do it to get data ? Thanks

Comment: @Oscar Jofre - can you please post the settion of your SQL_MODE -             
            
**SHOW variables LIKE 'sql_mode';**

Comment: @Bernd Buffen added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid subtraction and work only in timestamps:

```
WHERE  radacct.acctstarttime + INTERVAL radacct.acctsessiontime SECOND
     < NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MINUTE
```

(And it is more readable, in my opinion)

This 'composite' index *might* help performance:

```
INDEX(acctstarttime, acctsessiontime, AcctStopTime)
```

If you are having performance problems, consider normalizing columns that are wide, but repetitive.

Comment: That is working perfect and easy. I add on the question the new query result working.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a answer, but i cant format it in comment.

Which MariaDB Version you are using ?

you have seen this ?

> **Error handling**
>
> In MySQL and MariaDB before 5.3 wrong arguments to UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
>   returned 0. Starting from MariaDB 5.3 we return NULL for wrong
>   arguments to UNIX_TIMESTAMP().
>
> **Compatibility**
>
> As you can see in the examples above,
>   UNIX_TIMESTAMP(constant-date-string) returns in MariaDB 5.3 a
>   timestamp with 6 decimals while MariaDB 5.2 and MySQL returns it
>   without decimals. This can cause a problem if you are using
>   UNIX_TIMESTAMP() as a partitioning function. You can fix this by using
>   **FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(..))** or changing the date string to a date
>   number, like 20080101000000.
>
> https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/unix_timestamp/

Try this to find the wrong row

**check this - gives a error**

```
SELECT CAST(0 AS UNSIGNED) - 1;
```

**set sql_mode to**

```
SET sql_mode='NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION';
```

**check again - without a error**

```
SELECT CAST(0 AS UNSIGNED) - 1;
```

**query to find the wrong row**

```
SELECT *
FROM radacct
WHERE ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(radacct.acctstarttime) + radacct.acctsessiontime)) < 0
AND (AcctStopTime = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR AcctStopTime IS NULL)
```